# Get root folder in the Play Framework during production?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

I am working on a project where I have to save some temporary user generated files on the file system. In my dev environment I created a folder called `usr` in my root folder and user relative paths to read and write from the folder.

However when I run the server in production using `/.activator start`. The framework tries to read from `root/target/universal/stage/usr`.

I even tried using `Play.application.path.getPath` but I keep getting the same path.

Is there a way to get the root folder in production?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting correct root folder. The sense of `start` command is to verify how your application will run in production. So it build application, like you will do when you will push it to prod. And then "deploy it to prod" - unpack it to the `target/universal/stage` folder and run application from that folder. So `target/universal/stage` is your correct root folder.

Take in to attention - start command is deprecated:

> [warn] The start command is deprecated, and will be removed in a
>   future version of Play.
>
> [warn] To run Play in production mode, run
>   'stage' instead, and then execute the generated start script in
>   target/universal/stage/bin.
>
> [warn] To test your application using
>   production mode, run 'testProd' instead.

**Update**

You need to add to the `build.sbt` next code

```
mappings in Universal ++=
  (baseDirectory.value / "usr" * "*" get) map
    (x => x -> ("usr/" + x.getName))
```

This will say to sbt to add your "usr" folder to the "production package" (stage). Take in to attention - it will not "link", it will hard copy `usr` folder to the `target/universal/stage` so you will have `target/universal/stage/usr` that is copy of `usr` just before you run command `start`

Comment: Thank you, this is what I thought it was happening. So do you think is a good solution to include my `usr` folder in `target/universal/stage` rather than the actual root folder?

Comment: I think that the best solution would to put file in to the database. If you want to use file system - use the path anything you like. Your problem is that you want to get files uploaded in the dev mode from the prod mode and this is two different server environment.

Comment: Putting the file in a database is not an option unfortunately, I need to use the file system. Is there a cross platform way to get the actual root folder path? Every method I tried gives me `target/universal/stage` which makes sense from your answer. But I was looking for a way to just get the root path of the project without having to hard code it.

Comment: You do not need to think like this. "start" create different environment that is not linnked to your project. So thinking "just take my files from the project directory" is wrong, it's brake consistency of production environment. The correct question is "how to package "usr" folder to the production package". Look at my update please